# Application started in /etc/X11/xdm/Xsetup can't receive key presses

Tags: scripting, login, input

I'm using xdm (and I'd like to keep it that way) for a project and I need a terminal to run a script *before* the login prompt.

The script requires some user input, however, it doesn't seem to work.

Does xdm do something to stop the key presses being sent to the terminal (I'm using xterm if it matters)?

My /etc/X11/xdm/Xsetup looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# This script is run as root before showing the login widget.

#xsetroot -solid rgb:8/8/8

xterm -e /path/to/my/script.sh
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?